# javascript window.innerWidth conditional statement

Tags: javascript

I have a script which shows different content depending on the screen size, it looks like this:

```
if ((window.innerWidth < 1250 ))  {

//Do something

}
```

I am trying to set a greater than value as well as a less than value. I thought the follwoing would work:

```
if ((window.innerWidth < 1250 && > 750))  {

//Do something

}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: `if (window.innerWidth < 1250 && window.innerWidth > 750)  {`

Comment: You have to repeat comparison argument because you have to compare the innerWidth to each separate value.

Comment: check the answer..it will completely avoid all the confusion that you have..a very very simple solution!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Close:

```
if (window.innerWidth < 1250 && window.innerWidth > 750)  {
```

Answer (score 7):

When using Boolean operators (`&&`, `||`, etc), each side must be a completely valid Boolean expression on its own.  `&& > 750` is not a valid expression, since `> 750` cannot be evaluated as True or False.

What you want is :

```
if (window.innerWidth < 1250 && window.innerWidth > 750)  {
```

As both `window.innerWidth < 1250` and `window.innerWidth > 750` are valid expressions and can be resolved independently.

Answer (score 2):

You need to repeat the comparison argument after the `&&` to check with new value.

Use like this:

```
if (window.innerWidth < 1250 && window.innerWidth > 750) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 function between(val, min, max)
    {
        return val >= min && val <= max;
    }

    if (between(window.innerWidth,750,1250)) {
    //your code!!!
    }
```

Comment: Note this code behaves differently than what was originally posted.

Comment: the reason why i wrote this is because OP was confused about setting the conditions...and yes..this code behaves exactly the way accepted answer behaves..100% gaurantee!!!

Comment: You 100% guarantee `<` behaves exactly the same as `<=`?  Interesting.

Comment: can i give you a sample fiddle...let me know if it cant...http://jsfiddle.net/jayeshjain24/UmSss/2/

Comment: `-1` Because I don't like this answer.  For one, it doesn't explain the problem with the originally posted code, it only provides another (more complex) way to write it.  Second, the behavior is different.  The code would behave differently under certain circumstances.  I gave you an opportunity to fix it, but instead you just replied with some random Fiddle post that means absolutely nothing to me.  Thus, downvote.

Comment: i does not matter if get 10 more downvotes...but this definately is a better way to go about things..considering that their could be multiple situations where op needs to provide if conditions like that..why always write the entire stuff again and again..and its strange that at 200k reputation you find this code as complex..and the fiddle is a working example of my answer..anyways..we both dont have the accepted answer at the end of the day..Competition is always good and healthy!!!cheers